# When selected Non-Exempt in dropdown it should print blank value on PDF but while saving in database Non-exempt value should not be blank

Tags: javascript, xml

I have developed smartform in XML file using JavaScript. I have set a 'Open form' button (Please see attached image for reference) at the bottom of the form which opens PDF and entered fields on the form gets printed on the PDF.
For Example: If I enter signature in signature box as shown in attached image the that signature gets printed on Opened PDF.
I have to change some functionality related to smart form and PDF. As shown in second image there are three dropdowns where I can select Exempt and Non-Exempt options. 
In current functionality after clicking on 'Open form' button entered fields on the form gets populated on PDF.
For example If I select exempt or Non-Exempt in dropdown on the form then it gets printed on the PDF.

My question is: When I click on 'Open form' button and select 'Non-Exempt' option in one of the three dropdown fields (as shown in image) on smartform then it should not get printed on PDF however if I select 'Exempt' Option in same one of the three fields then it should get printed on PDF and both the values i.e. 'Exempt' and 'Non-Exempt' must gets saved in database(Non-Exempt value should not be saved in database as blank). I have wrote a function named PDFExport which export is used to open PDF and print values on it.

I am mentioning that function here that I made using JavaScript.
Please help how can I implement this functionality using JavaScript.

```
function pdfExport(psPDFPath) {
    var formObj = [ * form * ];
    var stepID = [ * me.stepid * ];
    if ((stepID == 3) || (stepID == 4)) {
        if (formObj.isValid(true)) {
            if (formObj.isSignatureValid('sfirstname,slastname', 'signature', true)) {
                setMdTaxMoneyVal();
                formObj.CreateVarHash("export=instant&Pdffile=" + psPDFPath);
                formObj.swSubmit("PDF.aspx?code=[*me.code*]", "_blank");
                formObj.setStatus('Ready');
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (formObj.isValid(true) && validateWithholdingData()) {

            if (formObj.isSignatureValid('sfirstname,slastname', 'signature', true)) {
                setMdTaxMoneyVal();
                formObj.CreateVarHash("export=instant&Pdffile=" + psPDFPath);
                formObj.swSubmit("PDF.aspx?code=[*me.code*]", "_blank");
                formObj.setStatus('Ready');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to print blank value on pdf using below function :

```
function BlankOption4() {
    var formObj = [ * form * ];
    var ReplaceMDTax5 = formObj.
        F("MDTaxLine4Exempt").getValue().replace("NonExempt", " ");
    formObj.F("MDTaxLine4Exempt").setValue(ReplaceMDTax5);
    alert("MDTaxLine4Exempt");
}
```

I called this function in PDFExport function its not working properly but issue is that on PDF Non exempt value is printing blank. This function is making Non exempt value blank on smart form due to which its printing blank on PDF also however I want Non exempt value to be blank on PDF but not on form and in database also it should not be blank.

I will be very thankful for any help.Thanks in advance. [Non exempt,exempt fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci99K.png)

Comment: please help me with this. I'm trying it from many days but unable to implement.Any help is appreciated.Thanks in  advance.

Comment: Hi all please help me on this. I haven't got any answer on this post. Thanks in advance.